# Button for downloading and installing .apk

Tags: ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 and I am looking for a way to implement behavior similar to play.google.com "Install" button.
For example, here we can see a button that onclick/ ontap will trigger .apk downloading and installation.
In my app I also gonna have such a button for my .apks. How to implement such behavior using Ionic 3?

Comment: You already installed the App from the play store. Why you want to include a download link?

Comment: I want to include links to other apps within my app.

Comment: may be if you upload the apk to the backend API server and you can download using the API URL.